# selecting column from another table matching id codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

In my database I have 2 concerned tables there are: ***ims_products*** and ***ims_order_details***. They have following structure:

***ims_order_details***

> - od_id(PK)
> - p_id(FK)
> - od_price
> - od_quantity

***ims_products***

> - p_id(PK)
> - p_name
> - p_category

I want to ***select p_category from ims_products where*** its ***p_id*** is same in ***ims_order_details***.

Comment: what you tried so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your model or controller file

```
$this->db->select('p_category');
$this->db->join('ims_order_details ','ims_order_details.p_id = ims_products.p_id,'inner');
$query = $this->db->get('ims_products');
if ($query && $query->num_rows()>0)
    return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select p. p_category
   from ims_products p
inner join ims_order_details o
   on p.p_id = o.p_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.p_category
FROM ims_products A
LEFT JOIN ims_order_details B
ON A.p_id = B.p_id
WHERE B.od_price IS NOT NULL
```